# R - How to detect the sign change in a column and add the values of that sign?

Tags: r, dataframe, addition

I have the following [data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bniIs.png). I would like to gradually add the negative numbers and after the negative values end, my code shall add the positive numbers and so on. For instance, in the following data set

```
c(-0.027029167, -0.027029167,0.015770833, 0.023270833, -0.011429167, 
  -0.030729167, -0.028029167, 0.011670833)
```

the code shall sum the first two negative values, and after it should now that positive values are next and sum them too, untill the end of the dataset.

So my end result shall look something like this:

```
-0.054058334
0.039041666
```

and so on.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hi, How long this dataset? There might be some vectorized approach, but if the dataset is very small, than simple loop might work too.

Comment: Hey, the dataset is around 600 lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this will do what you want.

```
x <- c(-0.027029167, -0.027029167,0.015770833, 0.023270833, -0.011429167, 
  -0.030729167, -0.028029167, 0.011670833)

r <- rle(x < 0)
tapply(x, rep(seq_along(r$values), r$lengths), sum)
#          1           2           3           4 
#-0.05405833  0.03904167 -0.07018750  0.01167083
```